# Remove post title in catogory page

Tags: title

Read all the posts and forums on the internet, but all the solutions didn't work.

My quotation page [is here](http://www.spreuken-wijsheden.nl/category/geluk/). I try to remove the page title because I already put it under as a quote.So no you see it doubled and we don't want that.

Does anybody know how I can do that, the theme is: Novita.

Comment: First, please don't add _"Help!" to titles. Coming here and asking a question makes it quite obvious that you need help. Also we can read all your information on your profile page, which is the reason that SE/SO doesn't allow signatures. So no need for thanks, etc. About your theme: This would be a thing we need - a link to the theme download. Without it, how should we know?

Comment: Sorry i didnt know that thankyou for the comment Kaiser.

This is the link to the template:
 http://newwpthemes.com/downloads/?theme=novita

Comment: Please always use edit.

Answer (score 1):

In your page template you can use the conditional statement [is_category($category)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) to determine if the header should show:

```
 if (!is_category('fun')){ the_title(); }
```

... OR ...

**Better:** You can create a [category template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) and not include the_title() in that template file. This is a cleaner way to ensure only that one category page leaves out the page title.